# How specify file filter in QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qfiledialog

I need to choose a directory with files "*.in".
But if i use `getExistingDirectory`, i can't specify file filter, so i can't see files.

But i need to see ONLY "*.in" files, i could be only choose a directory, not a file.
Now i use this code:

```
qDebug() << QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Выберите папку с файлами устройств"), "", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

And i can't see any files in chosen directory (in dialog).

How i can do this?

Comment: Use getOpenFileName instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` option. From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) of `getExistingDirectory`:

> On Windows and OS X, this static function will use the native file
>   dialog and not a QFileDialog. However, the native Windows file dialog
>   does not support displaying files in the directory chooser. You need
>   to pass DontUseNativeDialog to display files using a QFileDialog. On
>   Windows CE, if the device has no native file dialog, a QFileDialog
>   will be used.

To filter displayed files by extension you will have to do slightly more:

```
QFileDialog dlg(nullptr, tr("Choose Directory"));
dlg.setOptions(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog | QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
dlg.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
dlg.setNameFilter(tr("Directories with device files (*.in)"));
if (dlg.exec())
    qDebug() << dlg.selectedFiles();
```

When I tried this, the files that don't match the filter were still displayed, but in grey color (I tried on MacOS, maybe you will have more luck on Windows).

There is no standard way to prevent user from selecting a folder which contains no files matching the filter. A solution is to derive your own class from `QFileDialog` and override the `accept` function (not calling `QFileDialog::accept` from your override will prevent the dialog from closing).

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work with get-dir method. Would it be also acceptable to let the user select any of the *.in files and then getting the directory of that in-file using `QFileInfo::path`?

```
QString inFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
    this, 
    tr( "Выберите папку с файлами устройств "
        "выделив какой-либо из файлов устройств :-)"
      ), 
    lastSelectedDir, 
    "*.in"
);
QString dirName = QFileInfo(inFile ).absolutePath();
```